# Circuit Playground Express not showing CIRCUITPY drive

Tags: arduino, python

I got a Circuit Playground Express to serve as an [anti-slumper](https://github.com/mdinata/circuitpython/blob/master/antislump/slumper.py) device. Several mini-USB cables were power-only, and I tested them with the Arduino IDE and C code until one worked.

I reset the board to factory pressing twice on the Reset button. I see `CPLAYBOOT` as a drive, but not `CIRCUITPY`. But the board [should work for CircuitPython](https://learn.adafruit.com/installing-circuitpython-on-samd21-boards/overview):

> Some SAMD21-based boards, like the Circuit Playground Express, METRO M0 Express, and Feather M0 Express, are designed to work with CircuitPython out of the box.

How can I reset the board to show `CIRCUITPY` as a drive and take a CircuitPython file? Or do I need to install CircuitPython with the Arduino IDE, UF2, and a version of CircuitPython?

Comment: Here's what you need to do for going past the bootloader. https://learn.adafruit.com/welcome-to-circuitpython/installing-circuitpython

Comment: @kalyanswaroop So Circuit Playground Express does not come with Circuit Python out of the box? I'd be surprised if middle school students would need to do those UF2 steps in order to program the device in Python.